# SQL Query Schema and Data into One Row from 2 Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have data that was merged by accident in our production site, but we still have the data separated in our test site/database. I'd like to be able to query customer data from both databases to compare based on a customer's uniqueidentifer. What I'd like to see in the query results is the schema tables, columns, and primary uniqueidentifier keys of tables where the table has a matching foreign column containing the customer's key.

For instance, if the customer has an invoice the customer cst_key would be in the inv_cst_key of the ac_invoice. I need the primary key of that table, which would come from the inv_key column of that row. So if the customer had two invoices, two inv_key's would list as separate rows.

I installed ApexSQL Search to search the database uniqueidentifier columns for the customer key and it provided the table and foreign columns where the customer's cst_key existed (e.g.: inv_cst_key), but I still need the primary key (e.g.: inv_key) of that table row which the customer key resides. I tried using those search results to build something with excel (piecing tables, operators, columns, etc.) and copy/paste it to SSMS, but the query pulls millions of results the way it's setup...

```
DECLARE @cstkey uniqueidentifier
SET @cstkey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

SELECT cst_key, 
inv_key,
-- many more columns
FROM co_customer 
LEFT JOIN ac_invoice ON cst_key = inv_cst_key 
-- more LEFT JOINS
WHERE cst_key = @cstkey
```

Also, I know how to query data from 2 databases, but I don't know how to query so that I can see table and column names in a row next to the column's data.

```
DECLARE @cstkey uniqueidentifier
SET @cstkey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

SELECT cst1.cst_key AS cst_key_1, inv1.inv_key AS inv_key_1, 
cst2.cst_key AS cst_key_2, inv2.inv_key AS inv_key_2

FROM db1name.dbo.co_customer cst1
LEFT JOIN db1name.dbo.ac_invoice inv1 (NOLOCK) ON inv1.inv_cst_key = cst1.cst_key
INNER JOIN db2name.dbo.co_customer cst2 (NOLOCK) ON cst1.cst_key = cst2.cst_key
INNER JOIN db2name.dbo.ac_invoice inv2 (NOLOCK) ON inv2.inv_cst_key = cst2.cst_key

WHERE cst1.cst_key = @cstkey 
AND cst2.cst_key = @cstkey
```

I'd like the results to look something like this...

```
DB1 | T1 | PC1 | PC1 Data Key | FC1 | FC1 Data Key || DB2 | T2 | ...  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

DB = Database, T= Table, PC = Primary Column, FC = Foreign Column
Btw, the FC1 Data Key would also be the cst_key as mentioned above.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If you still have all the separate data in other databases, why are you trying to "unpick" the data in prod? Why not delete the merged data an re-import from your other sources?

Comment: Have you  considered using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to process the data. Using SSIS makes it easy to process data from multiple sources.

Comment: To get Table & Column info as tabulated data, you can use the Information Schema. e.g. SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable';. You can join this to the COLUMNS and TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tables to get primary key column names and then join in turn to your table data.

Comment: @Tony, our TEST db was last overwritten by Production a year ago, so I'll need this query to see what is to be added back to production from that year of additional data. Also, I have not considered SSIS, but I'll look into it, Thanks.

Comment: @SimonWray, It sounds like you're answering my inquiry. Perhaps you could answer this as an answer in a little more detail so I can fully understand? Thanks!